# Unpack/Repack android application inside another application

Tags: android, eclipse, apk, unpack

I have an application that use resource inside second application, and by some condition the resources inside second application should be changed, and now I want to unpack the second `.apk` file inside my main application and change its resource, then repack it and finally install it.

All two applications is mine and created with `eClipse LUNA`.

How can I do this inside the device?

Comment: Hi there. Was the below answer of any use? You do not seem to have accepted it or replied to it, and yet it is six months old.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot, I mean if they are two separate applications, because each application runs in its own process.

That said you can use [android:sharedUserId](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-element.html) in your *manifest.xml*, both apps should e signed with the same certificate

> The name of a Linux user ID that will be shared with other
>   applications. By default, Android assigns each application its own
>   unique user ID. However, if this attribute is set to the same value
>   for two or more applications, they will all share the same ID —
>   provided that they are also signed by the same certificate.
>   Application with the same user ID can access each other's data and, if
>   desired, run in the same process.

It will be something like the following

App 1

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.meg7.app1"
    android:sharedUserId="com.meg7.shared">
```

App 2

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        package="com.meg7.app2"
        android:sharedUserId="com.meg7.shared">
```

And use the following in app1

```
Context app2Context = this.createPackageContext( "com.meg7.app2", Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);// CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE
app2Context.getResources().getDrawable(resId);
```

What do you mean by

> resources inside second application should be changed